# Need to find out the which output nodes names needs to be pass for Tensorflowjs converter

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, tensorflowjs-converter

I am new to Tensorflow, I have developed a model which detects a special kind of card using the Tensorflow, OpenCV, I am properly able to detect the card using my webcam in the offline mode but I want to migrate it to the web (tensorflowjs)  but I am facing some issues in regarding to the conversion.

I have the checkpoints, meta, data files along with the frozen inference graph pb file

I have generated the nodes names list using the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf


modelName = './<path_to_meta_file>'

tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(modelName)
    graph_def = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()
    node_list=[n.name for n in graph_def.node]


print(node_list)
```

here is the output file
[Output node names using the tensorflow import_meta_graph()](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0c3bh8hy9nwvamd/output.txt?dl=0)

my concern is what should I pass in the output nodes names in the below command

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_frozen_model --output_node_names='<what to write here from that output txt file?>' ./frozen_inference_graph.pb ./web_model
```

I want to run my existing model using the real webcam on the client side, any solutions and suggestion would be highly appreciated

Setup Details:

Tensorflow 1.12.0

Python 3.5 using the Anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

For me the tensorflowjs_converter ran through by using "Placeholder" as an argument for --output_node_names:

`tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_frozen_model --output_format=tensorflowjs --output_node_names=Placeholder ./frozen_inference_graph.pb ./web_model`

Not sure if this is a valid solution, though, because even though the converter runs without an error message, I get the output from the model_pruner: "Graph size before: 1187 nodes, 1221 edges. Graph size after: 1 nodes, 0 edges." - so my input is effectively reduced to nothing, which doesn't seem to be right either.

---

Update:
After two more hours of research I found that the tensorboard indicates the node names (refer to [this page](https://developer.arm.com/technologies/machine-learning-on-arm/developer-material/how-to-guides/optimizing-neural-networks-for-mobile-and-embedded-devices-with-tensorflow/determine-the-names-of-input-and-output-nodes)). In my case it turned out that `--output_node_names=final_result` - and the Placeholder is not more than what the name already says, a placeholder that needs to be filled with valid content.